# SQLSTATE[42000] when using bindParam

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to implement a backend RESTful API in PHP from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHUxnUX7Y2Y.

```php
$app->get('/api/customers/{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = :id";

    try {
        // Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        // Connect
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $customers = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        $db = null;

        echo json_encode($customers);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});
```

when I want to use bindParam I always get an error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':id' at line 1

The server uses MySql "Server Version: 5.6.36-log - Source distribution"

Comment: You can't use a placeholder for the table name.

Comment: @Mikey thank you, I just updated the code with an example of WHERE id = :id

Comment: which api are you using to connect with?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I do not understand your question, I am trying to implement a RESTful API with PHP. The tutorial uses https://www.slimframework.com/ .

Comment: are you using `mysql_`, `mysqli_`, or any other than PDO? I have never worked with SLIM but far as I know, that error would be thrown if a differerent api than PDO were used to connect with.

Comment: Never mind, see Anton's answer below; that's why your code failed.

Comment: @Zoybe if Anton's answer didn't solve this, you will need to place a comment under his answer. If you're not present in the question anymore, you will need to edit your post to contain any (other) errors you may be getting. I have left the question now, good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is using PDO, use a prepared statement instead of a query. This means calling `prepare` and `execute` rather than `query`.

I have updated your code below as an example:

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt=>execute();
    $customers = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

You may also want to consider using `bindValue` instead of `bindParam` to simplify your code in this case. `bindParam` evaluates the value of `$id` when the statement is executed by passing it by reference, which seems unnecessary if the id won't change, so `bindValue` may suffice.

Reference manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I'm curious to know why you removed the reference link I added in an edit earlier https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45254605/2

Comment: My fault, @Fred-ii-. I was making an edit and I must have overwrote your changes. It should be back now.

Comment: No problemo. Well, it seems like the OP's "AWOL". I left [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254495/sqlstate42000-when-using-bindparam#comment77473433_45254495) earlier, but received no response, nor did they comment under your question. Lord as my witness I tried *lol*